Непонятный вывод jsonify
у меня простое api task manager, но меня очень бесит, когда тестирую в postman put запрос у меня выдает отсортировоанный словарь по алфавиту.
data = request.get_json()
task = task_service.update_task(task_id, title=data.get('title'), description=data.get('description'),
                                completed=data.get('completed'))
return jsonify(task.to_dict(),
               {"message": "Task updated successfully"}), 201 




def to_dict(self):
    return {
        'id': self.id,
        'title': self.title,
        'description': self.description,
        'completed': self.completed,
        'created_at': self.created_at,
        'user_id': self.user_id
    }

Вывод:
{
    "completed": true,
    "created_at": "Fri, 18 Oct 2024 15:32:09 GMT",
    "description": "drinked!",
    "id": 478,
    "title": "Buggi Wuggi",
    "user_id": 1
},
{
    "message": "Task updated successfully"
}


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Сортировка в json не имеет значения

Её конечно можно отключить через app.json.sort_keys, только вот если это вам прям жизненно необходимо, то скорее всего вы делаете что-то не так

Словарь и не обязан быть упорядоченным определённым образом, там главное наличие пар ключ-значение, а порядок их следования вообще говоря не гарантирован.
